# Eurasian nomads

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image: Empty crossword grid]

**Across**
1. Theatrical musical interrupted by a tram construction (12)
10. One-time Vatican resident's right to boycott Toyota vehicle (4)
12. Exhausted courier crammed small boxes (6)
13. Hong Kong criminals, having gotten FBI tail, scamper back (5)
14. Broadcaster broadcast its adoration (5,7)
16. Botched U-turn? After hospital admission, having zero injuries (6)
18. Of sound mind at heart, visiting Greek island from the east (5)
19. Palindromic woman paired with man, man paired with palindromic woman (4)
22. Take pains to avoid south Eurasian nomad (4)
24. Piece of religious literature written about God and the entrance to heaven, a land of wonders (5)
25. 15 down misinterpreted in Old English or in Scottish? Okay! (3,3)
27. Like some philosophers' comments on message boards, perhaps missing article supportive of rule of God (4-8)
30. Small part of Russia dancing on air (5)
31. Funky G & Funk Unit: "Start Fighting" (4,2)
32. Recording on the radio makes money in Africa (4)
33. Writer made retracted art in state's historical region (12)

**Down**
1. Lab worker described in comic strip – so funny! (12)
2. Covering with heavy metal top (7)
3. Work Mr Burton's initially announced moving into development (12)
4. Among others, it appeared after break-up of USSR (6)
5. Two times, 300 Spartans stuffing large bird with rival's head (4)
6. Unstable hit man in a European country getting mental disorder (12)
7. In broadcast, 9 down a native of Asia (4)
8. Consider Albert and Jack maybe having uniform brought up for literary nobleman (5,7)
9. Produce a .44 or 4-4? (4)
11. They say a portal leads to treasure (5)
15. Sore foot of tourist scratched in yacht at sea (4)
17. One prejudiced against people of Jewish faith, Ashkenazim included (4)
20. Asian dictator of old has slightly twisted arm (7)
21. Soccer-playing club appearing, only a single time, to get the better of opponent's goalkeeper (5)
23. Metal band from Canada forgetting what Backstreet was in 1997? (6)
26. You and I imprisoned, given ball and chain (4)
28. Part of Andros, a Bahamian island (4)
29. Boss breaks down and cries (4)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solved grid:

> [image: solved crossword grid]

Clue explanations:

> [image: clues with annotated answers]

Comment: Fast, and brilliantly solved... again.

Comment: Only 35 minutes to solve, very cool, haha